# Driver on Visual Studio Extensions Menu?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019, remote-debugging

I am trying to set things up so I can build an app on my laptop, deploy it on a Surface tablet over a USB A-to-A cable, and debug it on the tablet. As a part of this, I am trying to follow these directions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/provision-a-target-computer-wdk-8-1

I'm stuck at the following step:

*On the host computer, in Visual Studio, select the Extensions menu, point to Driver, point to Test, and select Configure Devices.*

In visual studio, all I see in the Extensions menu is "Manage Extensions" and "Customize Menu". This is VS2019 professional. I tried running it both as an admin and not.

What are they referring to?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I needed to install the Windows Development Kit on the host machine. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk. The way the instructions were written, I thought it was the target machine, which was wrong.